# Optimizing My Game App

Tags: .net

I want to create a game.
Backgammon.
i used to design my nuts and board in photoshop.
i saved nut as png.
and board as jpg.
for per that i have in game i created a picture box , and i bound png picture to that.
i know that this way is not correct.
please give me tips and guidelines.

---

seems my question is too general.
i change my question.
What element do I replace instead of pictureboxes?
what is the way for moving nuts?
for good performance and memory usage.
i putted my board in a panel and panel's Dock is fill in my form. but i know its not correct to put 30 picture boxes in form and moving them. my game is 2d. my challenge is to keeping nuts and moving them. better way that using pictureboxes

Comment: This question is far too general. Check out www.gamedev.net for some tutorials on how to get started.

Comment: I would agree that the question is a little general, but I think he is just wondering how to optimize the display of his images for the game.

Comment: My advice: Concentrate on getting the game logic to work first, then you can play around with graphics and so forth when the game itself works.

Comment: i edited my question. 
Dear Tony you are right :)

Comment: @ Brian Rasmussen:
i wrote Role engine and etc but some parts depends on graphic objects.
please give me your nice advices .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving PictureBoxes around *does* work, especially for a game like backgammon where things aren't moving all the time or moving very quickly.

The other "simple" way to do it is to make one big canvas, and override the onPaint event to manually draw in the images using the Graphics object (or something like that, it's been a while).

Otherwise, for more complex games, you'd want to get into having a 3D canvas to take advantage of hardware acceleration for graphics and such.

Comment: thank you.
i putted my board in a panel and panel's Dock is fill in my form.
but i know its not correct to put 30 picture boxes in form and moving them.
my game is 2d.
my challenge is to keeping nuts and moving them.
better way that using pictureboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I Created Nice photoshop Template.
i did import the template to Expression Blend.
and now i am going to Make Usercontrol for NUT and Dice.
thanks all.